# grails jasper plugin and jquery plugin conflict with asset pipeline

Tags: grails, jenkins-plugins, grails-plugin

Our project uses the jquery 1.11.1 version through the grails jquery plugin and is imported through the asset pipeline manifest (app.js).
Recently a team member added the jasper plugin and that includes jquery.js(v1.6.2) file which seems to make it through to the pipeline's output file over the jquery plugin version (1.11.1) no matter what i do. This happens on a jenkins build using grails wrapper (with clean-all war). For some reason, it works just fine on a local windows machine when done through terminal (grailsw war). 
Here is the app.js includes

```
//= require jquery
//= require js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min
//= require bootstrap
```

I have tried:

1. adding an plugin exclude (grails.assets.plugin."jasper".excludes = ["jquery.js"]. this didn't have any effect.
2. adding grails.assets.excludes = ["jquery.js"] excludes the file for sure (looking at the logs) but somehow the 1.6.2 version still finds its way to the compiled application.js

Any suggestions? The jasper plugin jira seems to not exist so couldn't raise this issue to them. Ideally they shouldn't include a jquery version in my opinion.

Comment: What version of Jasper are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the jquery grails plugin and moved to bower asset management for all web frameworks. 
Then changed the require path to point to the bower downloaded jquery file.

```
//= require jquery/dist/jquery
//= require bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Grails 2, an alternative workaroud is to remove the jquery file included with jasper plugin, you can do that with an event (*_Events.groovy* file) as follows

```
eventCompileEnd = { msg ->
    try{
        new File("target/work/plugins/jasper-1.11.0/web-app/js/jquery.js").delete()
    }catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e){
        log.error e.getMessage(), e
    }
}
```